# Storing a single variable in android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

My application doesn't require users to register, but it does ask for them to input their name and I wanted to persist that data. Currently I store the name in a 'User' object and query that table in the main activity. If there isn't a user object in the database then it asks for input, otherwise it just continues on. I'm trying to think if there is a better way to do this, but I can't quite think of any alternatives.

Comment: if you want to persist user data then you have to use App database  without doubt. whether you use android room or sqlite

Comment: I've read some about SharedPreferences and how they persists on close. Could I use this in anyway to avoid making database queries?

Comment: You still need to query a Preferences file. And lists can't be natively stored.

Comment: If you want to persist anything, it needs to be a file, or a database. (SQLite is just a file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your database size and structure .

If there are multiple users data with multiple information would be stored  then it advisable to use database instead of sharedPreference.

sharedPreferences are used for light weight data or for few amount of data only . whereas database is used to store multiple columns and multiple users data . on other side,SharedPreferences is quick compared to Database queries.

So check with your requirement . how much data will be stored and which type of information  you are storing .

Comment: SharedPreference worked perfectly! Stored the string just like I wanted it to without too much overhead, thanks!

Comment: @CalebWhittington i'm glad you found your best approach.